# char c[] = {'J', 'K', 'W'}; Why printf("%s", c) print "JKWJKW"?

Tags: c

Parts of the c code is as below:

```
char c[] = {'J', 'K', 'W'};
printf("%s\n", c);
```

And I don't know why it prints "JKWJKW" instead of "JKW".
Isn't `char c[] = {'J', 'K', 'W'}` equal to `char c[] = "JKW"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not equal: you forgot the terminating zero. It's present in "JKW", but not in the array initializer. As for why it prints "JKW" twice? By not zero-terminating the string, you've stumbled on undefined behavior. Your code can do pretty much anything at that point.

Comment: interesting, printf creates a string JKW\0 next to variable c and its printed both untill the end of string \0